# Is it possible to create a Python 3.8 virtual environment without admin privileges if there is only Python 3.4 installed? CentOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, centos, virtualenv

At my work they have installed Python 3.4 and I have created virtual environments using that version but now I need Python 3.8 to work on a personal project on my spare time. Is it possible to create a venv using Python 3.8 without having admin privileges?

We use CentOS for OS.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik the python3.8 binary is needed. So you would need to compile it from sources (meaning download source, compile, put result somwhere in your home). Then you can do venv normally.

Comment: Python 3.8 **binary** is needed!

Comment: Grab the [sources](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-382/), define `--prefix` to point to `${HOME}/local` for instance when configuring it, build, install, run. :)

Comment: @phd That is correct. I had mistaken it with my PyCharm venv creation. Then PyCharm installed already the binary and only `/usr/lib/libpython3.8.so` was missing.